# How to inject @Value into thymeleaf inline javascript

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this inline javascript using thymeleaf

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var contextPath = [[@Value("#{servletContext.contextPath}")]];

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

When my document y parsed and send to the client this is what is printed

```
<script>
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var contextPath = </script>
```

I have tried this

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var contextPath = [[${servletContext.contextPath}]];

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

but I'm getting the same result.

servletContext is the reference to the `javax.servlet.ServletContext` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is explained in [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-natural-templates).

Try with this:

```
var contextPath = /*[[${#ctx.servletContext.contextPath}]]*/ null;
```

Comment: thanks, but servletContext is the reference to the javax.servlet.ServletContext interface. What I wan to get is the context-root of my application.

Comment: thankyou it worked with var servletContextContextPath =/*[[${#servletContext.contextPath}]]*/ null;